# Create confirm box in mvc with out using jquery in view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In asp if I went to display confirm box in method I just use this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "confirm('Record Inserted Successfully')", true);
```

but in side mvc if I went to do same I will not find any way to do that

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: yes I will try to use scriptmanager.load which we  can use in asp but I will do same thing in mvc @teovankot

Comment: we could design a simple partial view for custom confirm box. then Return that partial view result. Using css you can display the position of it.

Comment: when an exception than I want to display confirm box . I don't need to return partial  view. @SubhabrataMondal

Comment: You can redirect to a page where the dialog is already rendered as part of the cshtml.

Comment: What's the objective here?  If you say you've tried to use scriptmanager, then it can't be because you want it to work when javascript is disabled.  So what's the point?  Have a read of this: [Stack Overflow - XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/346811)

Comment: yes but its is not possible with controller side

Comment: @Jay was that comment to me about returning an already rendered dialog?  That *is* server-side (via the controller).

Answer (score 1):

If you need simple confirm you always can use simple js [`confirm`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp) method.

For example if you want to confirm `form` `submit` - you san do it like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return confirm('Will we post?');">
```

If you have link with href you can do it like this in Razor syntax:

```
@Html.ActionLink("YourAction", "YourController",
    null, //here you can pass additional parameters to href
    new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want this?');" })
```

Comment: I will throw confirm box on controller  side  only

Comment: If we got an exception then I have to ask confirmation explicitly to perform action.

Comment: Again, i have no idea what you've got on your server side, edit your question please with a details

Comment: I just update my question with some detail please check its.